# Android NullPointerException on onCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: android, exception, menu, nullpointerexception, oncreateoptionsmenu

This is my code:

```
public class className extends Activity{
    private MenuActivity menuActivity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        try {
            ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
            Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class
                .getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
            if (menuKeyField != null) {
                menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
                menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        menuActivity = new MenuActivity(this, context, R.menu.menu);
        );
    }
    @Override


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menuActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);   // <--
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}

public class MenuActivity {
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = mRootActivity.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(typeMenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    }

    // ...
}
```

I receive a `NullPointerException` on row:

```
menuActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

This exception is present only some moble like Galaxy note.
Do you know why there is this exception?

Answer (score 1):

*// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);*

Comment: I've it "inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);"

Comment: on my mobile it works fine the problem is only some mobile, for example Galaxy note, it works fine also in emulator, I don't know why this initialization crash in some mobile and I don't know how to replicate this exception

Answer (score 0):

Change code from

```
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menuActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);   // <--
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

To

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);  // <--
    return true;
}
```

This work on my program.